# Is Kies a good way to backup phone data for use on another phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, samsung-kies

I currently own a Galaxy S3, and later this month I will be upgrading to an S6. I have rooted my S3, and as such have disabled a lot of the sync and backup services, including Backup Assistant.

If I backup my data in Kies to my PC (Pictures, Messages, contacts, etc), will these be transferable to the new S6? Or are they tied to this S3 model in some way?